# Can we query and update structure at different levels with lens?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I often use lens when dealing with nested structures (JSON from various APIs), and I'm worried that nontrivial data manipulations with lens are somewhat complicated.

By nontrivial I mean performing update on different node than the node I query for.

For example, I would:

- Drill down to obtain a foldable list of interesting values (like `price`)
- Apply a criteria on that list (like `max`) to identify the "owning" entity of the result (like `order`)
- Drill down again for some interesting value (say, `vip` flag of a customer)
- Finally, update yet another value in that structure (say add a new `item` free of charge to latest order)

A somewhat reliable strategy is to use "stages" where simple lens are used to extract interim results and apply new lens to narrow down further or update the result. But this is somewhat against the spirit of lens, where I should be able to update the whole structure.

Other times I'm lucky to find combinators like `maximumByOf`, `aside` but I feel that I lack vocabulary and understanding of the problem - what kind of combinators are sufficient for this kind of tasks?

Is there idiomatic way to to this with `lens`?

Comment: The lens you've described is not lawful. Perhaps that is why you are having trouble expressing it within `lens`? Maybe you can write your own function to put the stages, which you think are ugly, into a single function. You can also write the unlawful optic by hand, but you'll need to be a little careful with it.